# want to merge tiles of different jpg images and show it on map

Tags: linux, openlayers, openstreetmap, gdal

I have generated tiles of multiple jpg images using gdal2tiles. Now I want to merge all tiles of multiple jpg images and show it on map. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34755/want-to-merge-tiles-of-different-jpg-images-and-show-it-on-map

Comment: What server are you using? Do you want to use WMTS or WMS?

Answer (score 0):

Use [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) to make a single layer that references the tiles. E.g., make a listing of the files to be tiled, and make a VRT file:

```
$ ls -1 path/to/*.jpg > my_list.txt
$ gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list my_list.txt all_of_them.vrt
```

The `all_of_them.vrt` can be used by various GIS software.